# Order by Votes in Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, sum, eloquent

I have 3 Models... Category, Post, Vote

When viewing a category, I am showing an index of all Posts in that category. So I'm doing something like `foreach ($category->posts as $post)` in my view.

The question I have now is how can I order the posts based on the sum of votes they have?

I have standard relationships setup, so that a post hasMany votes.

Comment: are the sum of votes a value associated with each $post ? what are the array keys for each $post ?

Comment: No, the sum has to be calculated from `votes.votes` in the DB. So I'm trying to order by the sum of a column of an eager loaded relation... If that makes sense...

Comment: why can't you order using a DB query ?

Comment: Seems silly to do another query when I'm already eager loading them... Is there not a way to sum() and orderBy() while eager loading? Perhaps in the relationship itself?

Comment: maybe you can post your query as well

Comment: It's not much, all I'm currently doing is: `Category::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: why can't you call only 1 query that will combine your category,post and votes, order by vote desc ?. Does your framework have limitations when it comes to writing more advanced queries?

Comment: No, I just prefer working with what's already built if there is a way rather than building or executing a raw query. It's more of a Laravel/Eloquent question than MySQL. :)

Comment: Yes but your framework converts whatever you write to a raw query at the end, so you need to be able to use the function it provides so that you get the desired result.

Comment: You have to either build a join query to pull all information that can be sorted into the original query, or use Laravel's `Collection` class to sort posts based on their compiled votes. Using the latter does not require you to change your query, but may be slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either by defining a helper relation on the `Post` model and sorting the collection after the relation is loaded **OR** simply by joining the votes and ordering in the query.

1 RELATION

```
// Post model
public function votesSum()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Vote')->selectRaw('post_id, sum(votes) as aggregate')->groupBy('post_id');
}

// then
$category->posts->load('votesSum'); // load relation on the collection

$category->posts->sortByDesc(function ($post) {
    return $post->votesSum->aggregate;
});

// access votes sum like this:
$category->posts->first()->votesSum->aggregate;
```

---

2 JOIN

```
$category->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
   $q->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
       ->selectRaw('posts.*, sum(votes.votes) as votesSum')
       ->groupBy('posts.id')
       ->orderBy('votesSum', 'desc');
}]);

// then access votes sum:
$category->posts->first()->votesSum;
```

You can use scope for that:

```
// Post model
public function scopeOrderByVotes($query)
{
    $query->leftJoin('comments','comments.post_id','=','posts.id')
      ->selectRaw('posts.*,sum(comments.id) as commentsSum')
      ->groupBy('posts.id')
      ->orderBy('commentsSum','desc');
}

// then
$category = Category::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderByVotes();
}])->whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using repositories so I went with the second approach. It's not as elegant as I had hoped, but it works. Is there a way I can integrate that into my existing `return Category::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();`? Or do I have to load() after?

Comment: You can use `with` instead of loading afterwards. Also you can create suggested scope for that in order to make the code a bit easier to read in the repo.