# Writing Eloquent Query to find posts with most votes Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have been having trouble writing an Eloquent query that finds my post with the most votes. I have a votes table and a posts table. The votes table has an id column, a post_id column, a user_id column, and a vote column. If someone votes for a post the vote column is set to the value of 1. If someone downvotes a post the vote column is set to 0. I can find the amount of votes for one post by using the following query:

```
Vote::where('post_id','=', $post->id)->where('vote','=',1)->count()
```

How could I improve upon this query to find the posts with the most votes? I have tried coming up with a method and I just can't seem to do it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you considered adding an `orderBy()` to your Eloquent query? [laravel 4 how to order by using eloquent orm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: This is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418176/order-by-votes-in-laravel-orm/24419654#24419654

Answer (score 2):

Just do....

```
DB::table('votes')->orderBy(DB::raw('sum(\'vote\')'))
                ->groupBy('post_id')->get();
```

This will order your votes, by their SUM

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to order the posts by the amount of votes. Could this do that for me? I want to be able to return the posts title, and body and other things like that.

Comment: Well then all you gotta do Vote::where('post_id','=', $post->id)->orderBy('vote')->get()  If the above comment is actually what you want (all posts ordered by vote)  But your original question seems to say you wanted to find the post with most votes.